# Why isn't @font-face working on my website?

Tags: html, css

I've got a woff file named 'azonix-webfont.woff'. I added it to my website using @font-face. but it's not working. The text is displayed with the default font. Where's the error?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        @font-face
        {
            font-family: Azonix;
            src: url(azonix-webfont.woff);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
      <p style="font-family: Azonix;">Hello!</p>
</body>
```

The text is displayed in default font. I don't know where's the error.

Edit: OK, I found the answer. It started working when I posted the files to the server.

Comment: Are you sure the file `azonix-webfont.woff` exists (in the same directory as your html file) and is found by the browser (see the developer console in Chrome or Firefox by pressing F12)?

Answer (score 1):

You should upload your font to [transfonter.org](https://transfonter.org/) and convert. Will come css code with transfonter zip folder. And then you should change font url in css, according to place of your font files. Like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Cn Lt';
  src: url('../../fonts/Proxima/ProximaNovaCond-SemiboldIt.eot');
  src: url('../../fonts/Proxima/ProximaNovaCond-SemiboldIt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../fonts/Proxima/ProximaNovaCond-SemiboldIt.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/Proxima/ProximaNovaCond-SemiboldIt.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../fonts/Proxima/ProximaNovaCond-SemiboldIt.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
}
```